# "Pixel" terminology in Android documentation

Tags: android

I know that dip is standard for determining sizes on android. So when the documentation says "pixels" (for example in the Position segment of [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)), does it literally mean pixels or density independent pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's just pixel, not dp, but you always can convert it like that :

```
public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp,Context context){
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi/160f);
    return px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just wanted clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

All those pixels units are not scaled.